# Change enter key to tab

Tags: javascript

This code works to convert the enter key to the tab. But I want to work according to tabIndex and that the submission is done when placed on the last input before submit input:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {  
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' ) {
    var form = event.target.form;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, event.target);
   form.elements[index + 1].focus();
   event.preventDefault();
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're giving your inputs names, right? You could just check if event.target.name equals the name of the last input

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follow

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {  
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' ) {
    var form = event.target.form;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, event.target);
   if(form.elements[index + 1]) {
    form.elements[index + 1].focus();
   } else {
    alert('Ready to submit');
    //form.submit();
   }
 }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">

<input placeholder="Enter your first name"/><br/><br/>
<input placeholder="Enter your second name"/><br/><br/>
<input placeholder="Enter your email"/><br/><br/>
<input placeholder="Choose password"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
         document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' &&     event.target.type!=='submit' ) {
        var tidx  = +(event.target.tabIndex) +1,elems =     document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
        var tidx2 = elems[i].getAttribute('tabindex');
        var tidx3 = elems[i].getAttribute('type');
        if (tidx2 == tidx && tidx3!='submit') {elems[i].focus();
        event.preventDefault();  } }   
        }
        }
         );
           </script>
```